# Error missing ) after argument

Tags: javascript

tengo en mi base de datos un campo donde almaceno texto este puede contener caracteres extraños como comillas simples o dobles, arrobas, etc.
al tratar de mostrar este campo en un textarea en una ventana modal Bootstrap me da el error:

> SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
>   El texto que genera el error es:

```
cambiar item '3'
```

lo muestro de la siguiente manera:

```
   var div = document.createElement("div");
   div.innerHTML =data;
   textarea = document.getElementById('descripcion');
   textarea.value = div.innerText;
   $("#modalHallazgo").modal('show');
```

como veran data es el texto que contiene mi campo de base de datos, de esta manera prevengo o acepto hasta comillas dobles algo asi:

```
cambiar item "2"
```

pero el problema surge cuando intento aceptar comillas simples, quiza alguna idea o sugerencia gracias de antemano..!!

Comment: Cambia esta linea `div.innerHTML =data;` a `div.innerText =data;` y prueba si te da error.

Comment: tambien lo intente y da el mismo error..gracias..!! @denifersantiagofernandez

Comment: Has probado a escapar las comillas? `data = data.replace(/'/g, "\\'");`